# Why is $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} B & B \\ B & B \\ \end{array}} \right)$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B\in M_n$ be positive semidefinite .

Why is $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   B & B  \\
   B & B  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \right) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ with $x_1 ,x_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then we have 
\begin{align}
 \langle x, \left( \begin{matrix} B & B \\ B & B \end{matrix} \right)x \rangle &= \langle \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \right) , \left( \begin{matrix} Bx_1 + Bx_2 \\ Bx_1 + Bx_2 \end{matrix}\right) \rangle \\
&= \langle x_1 , Bx_1 +Bx_2\rangle + \langle x_2, Bx_1 + Bx_2 \rangle \\
&= \langle x_1 + x_2 , B(x_1 + x_2 ) \rangle \\
&\ge 0
\end{align}
As $x_1 + x_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $B$ is positive semidefinite.
Also, $$\left( \begin{matrix} B & B \\ B& B \end{matrix} \right)^\dagger = \left( \begin{matrix} B^\dagger & B^\dagger \\ B^\dagger & B^\dagger \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} B & B \\ B& B \end{matrix} \right).$$
So $\left( \begin{matrix} B & B \\ B& B \end{matrix} \right)$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: If $B$ were positive definite, would this prove that the block matrix is positive definite too?

Comment: No, as $x_1$ could be $-x_2$ and non-zero, in which case we have $\langle x, \left( \begin{matrix} B & B \\ B& B \end{matrix} \right) x \rangle =0$ where $x \neq 0$.